# Magento connect manager url not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm working with magento 1.9.2.4 on my local computer, I'm using XAMPP.

Everything is running fine on the front end and on the backend, the only problem that I'm having is that when I'm using magento connect manager (mysite.com/downloader) the url is not working properly.

I'm able to access the downloader but when I try to do something the url just loops, like this `mysite.com/downloader/?A=settings` and if I click something again the url will be like this `mysite.com/downloader/?A=settings?A=settings` and take me back to home.

It just loops and keep adding the click to the url and never refreshing the page. I did some changes on the .`htaccess` and nothing seem to be working.

Comment: in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your server if you have a folder /downloader then check a subfiles, if your problem is just to install some extensions, go to `https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/` copy the url extension install then download it in this site: `http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php`

This method is temporary the time to find the solution to your problem.